# HQL generate TOP() clause to Postgres database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.1

I have a software "jsf + spring + jpa" compatible with oracle, sqlserver, and postgres. However, currently there arose a problem when paging. The query generated for the Postgres database creates a TOP() clause that is not compatible with Postgress. I wonder how to generate LIMMIT instead of TOP.

```
@Query("SELECT new br.com.governa.admin.comum.entidade.visao.PessoaFisicaVisao("
            + "pessoaFisica.id, "
            + "pessoaFisica.nome, "
            + "pessoaFisica.cpf, "
            + "pessoaFisica.dataNascimento, "
            + "pessoaFisica.nomeMae) "
            + "FROM PessoaFisica pessoaFisica " 
            + "WHERE upper(pessoaFisica.nome) like %:nome% " 
            + "AND upper(pessoaFisica.cpf) like %:cpf% "
            + "AND upper(pessoaFisica.rg) like %:rg% " 
            + "AND (pessoaFisica.dataNascimento = :dataNascimento OR :dataNascimentoStr = null) "
            + "AND upper(pessoaFisica.nomeMae) like %:nomeMae% ")
    Page<PessoaFisicaVisao> findPessoaFisicaVisaoPaginado(
            @Param("nome") String nome, @Param("cpf") String cpf,
            @Param("rg") String rg, @Param("dataNascimento") Date dataNascimento,
            @Param("dataNascimentoStr") String dataNascimentoStr, @Param("nomeMae") String nomeMAe, 
            Pageable pageable)
```

The Spring Query annotation is generating this JPQL

```
select
    TOP(10) -- is not recognized PostGres SQL
    pessoafisi0_.id as col_0_0_,
    pessoafisi0_1_.nome as col_1_0_,
    pessoafisi0_.cpf as col_2_0_,
    pessoafisi0_.data_nascimento as col_3_0_,
    pessoafisi0_.nome_mae as col_4_0_ 
from
    admin.PESSOA_FISICA pessoafisi0_ 
inner join
    admin.PESSOA pessoafisi0_1_ 
        on pessoafisi0_.id=pessoafisi0_1_.id 
where
    (
        upper(pessoafisi0_1_.nome) like ?
    ) 
    and (
        upper(pessoafisi0_.cpf) like ?
    ) 
    and (
        upper(pessoafisi0_.rg) like ?
    ) 
    and (
        pessoafisi0_.data_nascimento=? 
        or ? is null
    ) 
    and (
        upper(pessoafisi0_.nome_mae) like ?
    ) 
order by
    pessoafisi0_1_.nome,
    pessoafisi0_.cpf asc
```

I'm using :
hibernate 4.2
Hibernate-jpa 2.1
Spring 4.0.5

Answer (score 0):

I was compiling the code for SQLServer and running the server in POSTGRES. Sorry.